# How can I include the section number of a deleted section in the deletion formatting applied by latexdiff?

Tags: sectioning, color, soul, latexdiff, strikeout

I have a document marked up by `latexdiff` and then edited to make it compile.

The current output for a deleted section is similar to this:

[image: deleted section]

How can I include the section number in the deletion markup? That is, I'd like '1 Deleted section' to all be in red and struck out, rather than having the '1' in black and only the 'Deleted section' red and struck out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,xcolor,kantlipsum}

%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF CFR PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\usepackage{xcolor}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD <

%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\section{\DIFdel{Deleted section}}%DIFAUXCMD
\addtocounter{section}{-1}%DIFAUXCMD
%DIFDELCMD <

\kant[2]

\section{Unchanged section}

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming that the only command you can base it on is the `\DIFdel` and that this command is used in other context too, I would say it is difficult to impossible. The number is already printed before `\@startsection sees the argument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It doesn't need to be automatic, so it can be based on anything which isn't too traumatic. The results of `latexdiff` don't even compile without editing, so an automated approach is out anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A manual version is this here. But I don't know if it fits in your work flow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,xcolor,kantlipsum}

%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF CFR PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\usepackage{xcolor}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD <

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\textcolor{red}{\sout{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}}
\makeatother
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\section{\DIFdel{Deleted section}}%DIFAUXCMD
\addtocounter{section}{-1}%DIFAUXCMD
%DIFDELCMD <

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother

\kant[2]

\section{Unchanged section}

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good. Let me try it, but I imagine I'll be back to accept this! (+1, of course.) It doesn't really need to fit into my work-flow. I expect to jump through hoops for journals at the submission stage. I just think it looks odd to have the black, unstruck section number when the heading is crossed out.

Comment: Background: I'm trying to emulate Word's 'track changes' because they want something like that, but my paper is in LaTeX .... (I find the result really rather distracting, but I find that with word processors' change-tracking, so maybe that's a sign I'm getting there?)